# Trying to use ReactCSSTransitionGroup for a Singleton

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, css-animations, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'd like to move something `bottom: +/- 100px`.

So that when focused, it slides up. When unfocused, it slides back down.

I've created this React `render()` :

```
var component = (      
  <div key={"trayResponder_" + this.props.trayOpen} >
  </div>  
);

return(
  <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="tray-responder">
    {component}
  </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
);
```

And then I toggle it's `key` state, by updating `this.props.trayOpen`

And then my Less is like this :

```
.tray-responder-enter {

}
.tray-responder-enter-active {
    .animation(slideUp 1s ease infinite )   
}
.tray-responder-leave {

}
.tray-responder-leave-active {
    .animation(slideDown 1s ease infinite ) 
}

.keyframes(slideUp;{
    0% {transform: translateY(100%);}
    50% {transform: translateY(-8%);}
    65% {transform: translateY(4%);}  
    80% {transform: translateY(-4%);}
    95% {transform: translateY(2%);}
    100% {transform: translateY(0%);}
});
.keyframes(slideDown;{
    0% {transform: translateY(-100%);}
    50%{transform: translateY(8%);}
    65%{transform: translateY(-4%);}
    80%{transform: translateY(4%);}
    95%{transform: translateY(-2%);}
    100% {transform: translateY(0%);}   
});
```

Which adopts from `animation.less` :

```
.keyframes(@name; @arguments) {
  @-moz-keyframes @name { @arguments(); }
  @-webkit-keyframes @name { @arguments(); }
  @keyframes @name { @arguments(); }
}

.animation(@arguments) {
  -webkit-animation: @arguments;
  -moz-animation: @arguments;
  animation: @arguments;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. Nothing occurs. No animation. Not really sure why.

**Update**

The trouble with ReactCSSTransitionGroup is that `enter-active` and `leave-active` occur simultaneously. Which doesn't seem to be a problem if you're toggling opacity. But if you're moving things up and down like I am, then you see both at the same time.

As seen here :

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting transitionEnterTimeout and transitionLeaveTimeout?

Comment: @UG_ Ah that's definitely a step in the right direction. I might be able to figure it out from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I understand, CSS Transition is for enter and leave. You want animation on hover, which can probably be achieved by using :hover selector.

```
const TransitionDemo = React.createClass({
  render : function () {
    return(
      <div className="demo"> 
        <p>Some Text Here</p>
       </div>  
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(<TransitionDemo trayOpen={1}/>, document.getElementById('root'));

//css

.demo {
  height : 100px;
  position : relative;
}

.demo p {
  position : absolute;
  bottom : 0px;
  transition : all 1s ease;
}

.demo:hover > p{
  bottom : 50px;
  transition : all 1s ease;
}
```

See this pen : http://codepen.io/umgupta/pen/dNNLxL

Comment: Actually I'm looking for `:focus`. But the trouble is is that focus blurs when you select the div's children. Any adding/removing a class re-renders the entire component thus preventing a pure CSS animation. And if I use React CSS Transition Group, it seems to strictly apply to opacity 0-1, not for something moving up and down. What to do! :D

Comment: It applies to things other than opacity too. I have tried. You can try simple move up or down with transform:translateY(1000px)

Comment: I tried that as well, but it seems React CSS Transition Group creates two divs that float on top of each other. So the `enter-active` and the `leave-active` occur simultaneously. Which would be ok if I was toggling opacity, as I would only see one. But I'm moving an item, then I see both swapping sides at the same time.

Comment: I added a Gif to the bottom of my question